# Does -s always return zero on a directory in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have always seen -s return zero on a directory (in Windows), but I don't know if I can rely on that.  It would only remove a few characters from a line of code, but as a minimalist, I want to know if I can get away with it.

Edit:  For instance, will `-s` always give the same result as `-d ? 0 : -s` ?  Apparently not on Linux (see answer from Kjetil S.), but I'm curious about Windows.

Comment: Directories on Unix systems contain at least 2 entries (`.` and `..`) so they're never empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of minimalist who would take out the seat belts of a car or remove the life raft on a yacht? ㋛

In Linux `-s $dirname` always seems to return at least 4096 even if the directory is empty. On the file system I use anyway. To check if something is a directory, use `-d $dirname`.

Comment: I wanted to use this `$tot += -s;` instead of this `$tot += -d ? 0 : -s;`  Those seatbelts are so distracting.  I think it will work on my Windows system, but since I hope to escape from Windows some day, I guess I'll keep the seatbelts.

Comment: Maybe `$tot += -f ? -s : 0;` is better then since there are other "file" types besides directories and files. At least in Linux it is: `block files`, `special files`, `FIFO`s, `symlink`s.

Comment: @ArnoldCross You should add that explanation to your question.

Comment: Yes, I was using -f at first.  Then I started thinking that I might miss a file that isn't a "plain" file.  (not sure what that really means in Windows).  Since I really just want to skip folders, I changed to -d.  Then, I got to thinking that -s gives me all the information I need, but I wasn't sure.  Thus, the SO post.

Answer (score 1):

`-s` doesn't always return zero for directories. It may always return zero on Windows, but I know of no such guarantee. It might be possible that `-s` behaves differently on different Windows system or for different file systems. And it's obviously possible that it might behave differently in different versions of Perl.

And why? Is

```
defined( my $size = -s $qfn )
   or do {
      warn("Skipping $qfn: $!\n");
      next;
   };

$total_size += $size;
```

or

```
stat($qfn)
   or do {
      warn("Skipping $qfn: $!\n");
      next;
   };

$total_size += -s _;
```

really better than

```
stat($qfn)
   or do {
      warn("Skipping $qfn: $!\n");
      next;
   };

$total_size += -s _ if -f _;
```

In other words, it really a good idea to rely on the reader knowing that directories and whatever other type of special files might exist all return a file size of zero, especially when you don't know that yourself?